# angularJS pre-binding not showing

Tags: angularjs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example59-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="bindExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($timeout) {
      $timeout(function(){
         this.name = 213;
      }, 1000);
    });
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController as ctrl">

  Hello <span ng-bind="ctrl.name">aaaaaaaaaa</span>!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why at this example i don't see "aaaa" text?
Can some body answer?
UPD: i addedd $timeout for better explane my question

http://plnkr.co/edit/e8S0VI5zRo3OgpW5wIgU

Answer (score 0):

[ng-bind docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind):

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the
>   specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to
>   update the text content when the value of that expression changes

`ctrl.name` is `undefined`, therefore your inner text is set to undefined and you get a blank span...

You should uncomment `this.name = 123` in your controller to assign it a value.

If you want to assign a default value you could use the OR operator:

```
ng-bind="ctrl.name || 'aaaaaa'"
```

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4i3qnmMVf5vLPySyiQlc?p=preview)

Comment: i addedd $timeout for better explane my question

Comment: @PavelEremin I see what you mean, you want `aaaaaaaaaa` to be the default value until `name` is set? Use an OR operator (updated answer)

Comment: is it good practice "use or operator"?  I remember, that my example with <span ng-bing="count">loading...</span> works on previos versions angularJS

Comment: I would say it's fine. As long as it's in your View and not your Controller. You may even argue that you should set `ctrl.name = "aaaaaa"` to begin with as that is literally the data for the span

Answer (score 0):

**update**:

when you decide to use $timeout to update  a variable on the 'this' (controller), you must preserve first the value of 'this'. this with the addition of @RGraham answer to use the 'or' operator will result in:

```
angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($timeout) {
      var that = this; 
      $timeout(function(){
         that.name = 213;
      }, 1000);
    });
```

html:

```
Hello <span ng-bind="ctrl.name || 'aaaaa'"></span>!
```

that'll show 'aaaaa' for 1 second until that.name is updated to '213'

updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTi4hVRhTKJzN1ykyQne?p=preview)

---

see the **[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)**:

> The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

if you want the 'name' property value to appear, uncomment it and it'll show '213' inside the span.

Comment: no, I want saw "aaaaa" text first, but it doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

Following will work. Use script in head. Use $scope instead of this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example59-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $timeout) {

      $timeout(function (){
         $scope.name = 213;

      }, 1000);

    });
  </script>  


</head>
<body ng-app="bindExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    Hello
    <span ng-bind="name">aaaaaaaaaa</span>!
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You are capturing different javascript scope to this.ngBind is replacing your 'aaa...' with "" because $scope.name is undefined. Define 'name' with initial value 'aaa...' in your controller. So if you wish to use as-syntax then capture this like here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example59-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $timeout) {

      var self = this;
      this.name = 'aaaaaaaaaa';

      $timeout(function (){
         self.name = 213;

      }, 1000);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak ng-app="bindExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as ctrl">
    Hello <span ng-bind="ctrl.name"></span>!
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```